# Polling consumer group lag over HTTP in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to see the remaining lag in near real-time from Kafka for a particular consumer group. The closest thing I've done is run the `describe` script from Kafka binaries, but it's slow and unreliable. We are trying to programmatically do this to perform some conditional logic within our ETL pipeline.

My first thought is to garner metrics within the consumer and publish over statsD to new relic or datadog then poll over HTTP. This is something I would do long-term. Is there a shorter-term, simpler approach to poll the consumer lag for a particular group?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java Admin Kafka API quite easily to expose this over command line or as an HTTP call quite quickly with Spring Boot (could avoid any metrics for each app individually since Admin API could do it for any group).

See link for an example: https://gquintana.github.io/2020/01/16/Retrieving-Kafka-lag.html

Code taken from example above.

Get all groups:

```java
adminClient
.listConsumerGroups()
.valid().thenApply(r -> r.stream()
.map(ConsumerGroupListing::groupId).collect(toList())).get();
```

Get highest offset in a set of partitions:

```java
consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
```

High level on connecting them together to get lag:

```java
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> consumerGroupOffsets = getConsumerGroupOffsets(groupId);

Map<TopicPartition, Long> topicEndOffsets = getTopicEndOffsets(groupId, consumerGroupOffsets.keySet());

Map<Object, Object> consumerGroupLag = consumerGroupOffsets
.entrySet()
.stream()
.map(entry -> mapEntry(entry.getKey(), 
new OffsetAndLag(topicEndOffsets.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue().offset())));
```

Comment: please  mapEntry dont work here ".map(entry -> mapEntry(...)"  it give cannot  resolve methode mapEntry